# When I try to recover a ssh-key I get "Bad passphrase, try again for"

Tags: ssh

I have saved a ssh-key in my lastpass account and I recovered in the past. I have recently formatted the computer (now I have OSX 10.12.3) and I need to recover this ssh key.

First I go to my lastpass account and I copy and paste the content to this files

```
~/.ssh/mykey
~/.ssh/mykey.pub
```

then I change these files permissions

```
$ chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/mykey
$ chmod 0644 ~/.ssh/mykey.pub
```

this key has a passphrase, when I try to add it to the ssh keyagent like this

```
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/mykey
```

and type the passphrase I get

> Bad passphrase, try again for /Users/agustin/.ssh/mykey

I've got the same error in both OSX and Ubuntu, but I am sure the passphrase is ok

Comment: Regardless of ssh-add: are you able to use this key, using that password, opening some ssh session?

Comment: @SYN thank you. I tried this `ssh -i mykey deploy@serverip`, but it did not work

Comment: Like a bad passphrase again?

Comment: Yes, it prompt for it 3 times and then it prints "Permission denied (publickey)."

Comment: And like... You're *really* sure to remember your passphrase? There's no caps lock, num lock, ... whatever apple lock I assume Mac could have, ...?

Comment: I am sure because I used tone of times. I tried both, to type and to copy and paste to avoid any chance of a typo.

Comment: Then are you *certain* that key you're using today is the same you were using before?

Comment: Are you using the right keymap (aka. keyboard layout)? It already happened that I was confused about failed attempts for some time until I realized that I has forgotten to set a german keyboard layout.^^

Comment: @JojOatXGME thank you for your comment, I checked that, and I also copied and pasted just in case, but it did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenSSH since some version (7.1 or so) [responds "wrong passphrase" to any error in OpenSSL](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2522) (usually format), there is pending fix, but I assume that the private key is somehow malformed or in format that is not supported by OpenSSH (ppk?).

Comment: thank you for the answer. I think it is related with what you wrote, but the key I generated with ssh-keygen and its format is `Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC`

Answer (score 0):

If you have copied your private key (say using clipboard copy and paste,) and you missed even one character, say, a trailing dash ("-"), ssh-add will still prompt you for a passphrase, and will say it's bad no matter what you put in.